# Run two services in same Docker container on CoreOS?

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

I'm kinda new to Docker and CoreOS.  I think I'm just a bit unclear on the concept of containers and how they relate to each other.

I'm trying to set up a CoreOS-based server that runs two services: a custom server (call it myserver), and a memcached server (that will be accessed only by myserver).

So I think I got as far as installing a myserver.service file on the CoreOS machine, that can successfully start upi myserver using a line like this:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/docker start -a my_container || /usr/bin/docker run --name my_container my-image /usr/local/bin/myserver'
```

So my question is, in order to start up the memcached server, do I create a new memcached.service file in CoreOS?  If so, should it use the same container "my_container" as the custom server?  If they don't use the same container, will myserver be able to reach the memcached server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brooks,  Good news.  I have an example ( https://github.com/brianredbeard/memcache-tools ) of just that which was written using CoreOS.

In this case you would have two containers with two systemd units.

Memcache.service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Memcached Server
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %n -t -i memcache
```

Worker.service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=My worker container
Requires=Memcache.service
After=Memcache.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name %n -t -i --link memcache:memcache my_container
```

What this will do is take the first container named *memcache* and present a number of variables into *my_container* in the form:
**MEMCAHCE_PORT_11211_TCP_???**, e.g.**MEMCAHCE_PORT_11211_TCP_HOST** & **MEMCAHCE_PORT_11211_TCP_PORT** which can then be consumed inside your program.

Take a look at the dump, load, and sample scripts as well as the Dockerfile and README.md in that example.

Comment: Brian, thanks so much.  Just a few requested clarifications: Why do you need "-t -i" in each if the "docker run" commands (I understand what they do, just not sure why they're needed)?  It looks like in both "docker run" commands you're using the name of the container instead of the image followed by a command, can you do that?  And just to be clear, you are using two completely separate images/containers, and the only way they communicate is via TCP using the injected connection parameters?

Comment: In reverse notation! 

1) yes, the only way the containers communicate is through TCP.  There is no direct file access nor any IPCs in use.  Only vanilla TCP.

2) That would be the name of the image, I just simplified it (in the same way that "busybox" can be called directly.  Additionally you could tag it locally to achieve whatever name you wanted.

3) Systemd by default runs processes in the foreground and can monitor/control them using normal signaling mechanisms.  In this case, having both -t and -i would also allow you to attach into the container for troubleshooting.

Comment: 4) Bonus round - On top of using ExecStart you should add an ExecStop line which would be of the form "ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop %n".  That will then give the systemd unit a graceful way to handle shutdown of the processes.